# How to copy contents of a span into its title attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, title

I have this code now

```
var i,
$spanc = jQuery("#menu").find("span").filter(":not(.stepnumber)");
        for(i in $spanc){
            $spanc.eq(i).attr("title", $spanc.eq(i).text());
         }
```

is there a way I can make it simpler?
Thanks for any suggestion or help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep:

```
jQuery("#menu span:not(.stepnumber)").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());
});
```

You can use `.each()` to iterate over a jQuery collection. `this` refers to the current object in the loop. You can also combine selectors into one string, `$('#menu span')` is the same thing as `$('#menu').find('span')`.

Comment: yes but internally jquery will use find in case of $("#menu span") so if we do $("#menu").find("span") will be faster ..is n't ?

Comment: I'd think two function calls are always more expensive, even if .find would be used internally. And this way it's simpler and the possible impact to performance is negligible.